# Mouse cursor is flickering and disappearing

Tags: dell, cursor

After installing Ubuntu 14.04, my cursor is disappearing on my laptop (Dell inspiron 5110 with nvidia gforce GPU). I tried several answers, but the problem is not solved.

I tried this:

```
Open System Settings > Displays. In the Displays window, you will see an Unknown monitor. Click it and disable it.
```

and this answer:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Both solutions did not work. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by installing the Nvidia GeForce GPU drivers using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic
```

Comment: Do you have the same for AMD ATI GPUs?

Comment: This made the whole desktop unusable after login. Screen is frozen, cant click anyhthing. Made things so much more worse.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a graphic driver issue.

Go to Ubuntu software center -> Edit -> software Sources -> Additional Drivers.

Select the default Nvidia driver that comes without update and let it install. Reboot and check.

Let us know if this works.

Comment: i try to set up Nvidia and can't get my desktop after remove it from shell i get my desktop

Comment: There are a bunch of drivers in the driver list for graphics. Try Them all. There must be like 4 of them. See if any of them works for you.

Comment: i solved this problem by install nvidia gforce GPU using this command `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus linux-headers-generic`